# obtener un resultado especifico de un JSON con varias tablas con laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel, json, condiciones

como puedo obtener el resultado de un json, funciona perfectamente con el foreach pero solo necesito el resultado de 1 campo para validar.
estoy usado laravel 6

```
    {
  "id": 175,
  "amount": 555,
  "amountFlight": 5500,
  "amountHosting": 3000,
  "reservationKey": "0",
  "ticketNum": "0",
  "invoiceNum": "0",
  "paymentMethod": "Efectivo",
  "client_id": 298,
  "user_id": 7,
  "intinerary_id": 251,
  "created_at": "2019-11-13 20:08:17",
  "updated_at": "2019-11-13 20:08:17",
  "client": {
    "id": 298,
    "dk": "ASD123"
  },
  "intinerary": {
    "id": 251,
    "intinerary_type_id": 3,
    "flight_type_id": 1,
    "created_at": "2019-11-13 20:08:17",
    "updated_at": "2019-11-13 20:08:17",
    "hostings": [
      {
        "id": 96,
        "hotel": "hotel 1",    
        "date": "2019-11-13",
        "nights": 3,           <= este es el dato que quiero obtener 
        "intinerary_id": 251,
        "created_at": "2019-11-13 20:08:17",
        "updated_at": "2019-11-13 20:08:17"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

con el foreach de esta manera trae todos los datos

```
@foreach ($tickets->intinerary['hostings'] as $host)
   <p>Hotel: {{ $host->hotel }} # Noches {{ $host->nights }}</p>
@endforeach
```

pero necesito validar que el numero de noches sea mayor a 0

Answer (score 0):

Pon un if.

```
   @foreach ($tickets->intinerary['hostings'] as $host)
       @if({{ $host->nights }} > 0)
       <p>Hotel: {{ $host->hotel }} </p>
       @else
        <p>Hotel: {{ $host->hotel }} No tiene plazas</p>  <-- el else es opcional
       @endif
    @endforeach
```

Comment: necesito obtener el dato en una variable sin que entre al fore each

Comment: Puedes cogerlo directamente con [Un numero aqui] para acceder al objeto, te recuerdo que tienes un array, por lo tanto, o lo recorres, o accedes directamente al objeto.

Comment: te refieres a  `$tickets->intinerary['hostings'][0]->nights` ?

Answer (score 0):

Si tienes varios hoteles dentro de `hostings` y quieres coger solo los hoteles donde sus noches sean mayor a 0, puedes convertir el array en un objeto `collect` de laravel (aunque en el controllador seguramente ya lo sea) y usar la función `filter`:

```
$hostings= collect($tickets->intinerary['hostings']);

// Así puedes obtener los hoteles que tienen noches disponibles y descartar los que no
$hotelesFiltrados = $hostings->filter(function ($hotel) {
    return $hotel['nights'] > 0;
});
```

Si a tu vista le pasas los `$hotelesFiltrados` se mostrarán solo los que tienen disponibilidad.

En caso de que no quisieras ocultarlos en la vista, sino simplemente marcarlos como "no disponibles", también lo podrías hacer (mediante la función `map` o con un simple `foreach`) pero te aconsejo que traslades la mayor lógica posible a tu controlador dejando en la vista las comprobaciones mínimas.

Comment: gracias me sirvio mucho :)